# Dropdown menu across multiple buttons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of buttons built in an ng-repeat loop. I want a drop down menu to be shared with them all.

The menu would have to understand the context / underlying object within the button, so that any action applied from the menu only affects that record.

I've been trying to follow through some bootstrap examples here:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

However once I have more than one menu, neither of the menus load, seen in this Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SIfEw0lxwen8YDAVKDfA?p=preview

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">


    <!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Second button -->
    <div id="hello" class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also can't get my head around how to make the menu a re-usable object given that it has to dynamically apply actions to whichever button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fiddling with your plunkr.

Please see this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zhzpIoIgoaxUkjEbAQuT?p=preview

According to the docs,
You can either use is-open to toggle or add inside a  element to toggle it when is clicked.I think the issue was with you using both isopen and dropdown toggle directive.Also regarding making the menu a reusable component,we would go for making the menu a custom directive which can accept a two way bound array scope variable as input for its menu items

So it would be like this

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-repeat ="button in buttons">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        {{button.name}}<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
<menu items-array="button.menuitems"></menu>
</div>
```